# Tensorflow Training Data load error: could not convert string to float:

Tags: python, csv, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

**I am trying to create my own custom dataset for the training of the model efficientdet_lite3, but when I run this code (The data csv file has the same format as the one specified on this link https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_object_detection):**

`train_data, validation_data, test_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_csv(‘data.csv’)`

**The error that i get from the above code:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File “”, line 1, in
File “/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py”, line 197, in runfile
pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars) # execute the script
File “/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py”, line 18, in execfile
exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, ‘exec’), glob, loc)
File “/Users/maryam/PycharmProjects/sp/newmodel.py”, line 23, in
train_data, validation_data, test_data = object_detector.DataLoader.from_csv(‘data.csv’)
File “/Users/maryam/PycharmProjects/sp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/object_detector_dataloader.py”, line 292, in from_csv
cache_writer.write_files(cache_files, csv_lines=csv_lines)
File “/Users/maryam/PycharmProjects/sp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/object_detector_dataloader_util.py”, line 247, in write_files
for idx, xml_dict in enumerate(self._get_xml_dict(*args, **kwargs)):
File “/Users/maryam/PycharmProjects/sp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/object_detector_dataloader_util.py”, line 380, in _get_xml_dict
xml_dict = _get_xml_dict_from_csv_lines(self.images_dir, image_filename,
File “/Users/maryam/PycharmProjects/sp/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_maker/core/data_util/object_detector_dataloader_util.py”, line 337, in _get_xml_dict_from_csv_lines
xmin, ymin = float(line[3]) * width, float(line[4]) * height
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ‘’
```

**Here is a sample of my dataset (data.csv):**

```
TEST,/Users/Downloads/tiny-imagenet-200/test/images/test_1863.JPEG,,,,,,,,

TEST,/Users/Downloads/tiny-imagenet-200/test/images/test_9550.JPEG,,,,,,,,

TRAINING,/Users/Downloads/tiny-imagenet-200/train/n02927161/images/n02927161_58.JPEG,n02927161,16.0,0.0,,,63.0,63.0,,

TRAINING,/Users/Downloads/tiny-imagenet-200/train/n02927161/images/n02927161_244.JPEG,n02927161,0.0,0.0,,,63.0,63.0,,

VALIDATION,/Users/Downloads/tiny-imagenet-200/val/images/val_8298.JPEG,n03014705,0.0,11.0,,,63.0,63.0,,

VALIDATION,/Users/Downloads/tiny-imagenet-200/val/images/val_8299.JPEG,n03770439,10.0,38.0,,,27.0,49.0,,
```

Is there a possible answer for this problem?

Thank you

Comment: the error  message suggests that you've got blanks in your csv that aren't being converted to NaN values when the file is read.  Maybe you could open the file in a pandas dataframe and see if you still get the same error?

Comment: The empty spaces that were shown on pycharm when i opened the data.csv gets displayed as NaN using the pandas dataframe

Comment: You need to fill NaN value with some real number. NaN value cannot be handled by model. Use pandas to fill NaN value, you can find [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html) how pandas handles missing/NaN value.